# JBOSS JSP precompile | out dated jsp error

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jboss

I am trying to precompile JSPs in our WAR. My ant script does this in 2 parts. First it creates the source, and then it compiles.

Initially a few source files are created. thereafter, the following error is thrown:

```
  [jasper2] 2010-11-12 16:58:49,865 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.JspC] [processFile] [Thread:main] - [Processing file: /categoryLanding/content/jeans_body.jsp]
  [jasper2] 2010-11-12 16:58:49,868 DEBUG [org.apache.jasper.JspC] [processFile] [Thread:main] - [/category/content/body.jsp is out dated, compiling...]
```

Any ideas what could be causing the jsp to be viewed as an outdated one?

Answer (score 0):

Is your ant script not touching .jsp file dates by any chance?

From http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.java.html

```
// If compile is set, generate both .java and .class, if
1174               // .jsp file is newer than .class file;
1175               // Otherwise only generate .java, if .jsp file is newer than
1176               // the .java file
1177               if( clc.isOutDated(compile) ) {
1178                   if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
1179                       log.debug(jspUri + " is out dated, compiling...");
1180                   }
1181   
1182                   clc.compile(compile, true);
1183               }
```

Comment: Hey,

I think the precompile is working as intended. I just revisited the prblem and noticed that I get the following error:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Need to establish the root cause.